# Invalid command name "Agent/rtProto/OSPF"

Tags: linux, tcl, patch, ns2, ospf

I have installed the OSPF [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996634/how-to-apply-the-ospf-patch-to-ns2-2-35-on-ubuntu-14-04) for `ns2` and it installs correctly. Now when I try to run the `tcl` examples of the same patch with command `ns ospf0.tcl` it gives this error:

```
(TCL) Creating simulator & trace files...
(TCL) Setting up nodes and links...
(TCL) Configuring traffic objects...
(TCL) Configuring routing protocol...
invalid command name "Agent/rtProto/OSPF"
while executing
"Agent/rtProto/OSPF set helloInterval 1"
(file "ospf0.tcl" line 132)
```

[Here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5305934#post5305934) someone says it `indicates a failed build. (Or you are using a wrong executable 'ns'.)`, but the patch installed with no error. I used to run tcl files with `ns` smoothly without the patch and without OSPF. I have `ubuntu 14.04` with `ns2 2.35` and have applied `10-ospf4ns2.34` patch. Any ideas whats wrong? Also it would be very helpful if someone just gave me the `nam` file to simulate or even the trace file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ns-2.35 :
The patch `10-ospf4ns2.34-base.patch` will fail with **common/packet.h** .

Please read post #4 [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-patch-ospf-in-ns2-34-a-4175514187/#4)
... about » **ospf_ns235.patch** «

Here's what you can do:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 : $ sudo apt-get remove ns2
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
```

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S...ew?usp=sharing

```
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
$ patch -p0 < ospf_ns235.patch
```

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S...ew?usp=sharing

```
$ ./install
$ cd ns-2.35/
$ sudo make install 
$ cp ns ns-ospf
$ sudo cp ns-ospf /usr/local/bin/
$ cd tcl/ex/ospf/
$ mkdir out_ospf0 out_ospf1 out_ospf2 out_ospf3 out_ospf4 out_ospf5 out_ospf6 out_ospf7 out_ospf8 out_ospf9
$ ns-ospf ospf0.tcl
.
.
$ ns-ospf ospf9.tcl
```

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow` and thanks again for also answering here.

Comment: Another question man, how are you setting the sentences in the trace file `set sim_annotation {Agente OSPF ...}}` which shows in `nam`? Is there somewhere I can change it, beside changing all the nam file lines? I want them to be english